# Saving after termination

Tags: android, listview, state, save

In my android application I have a listview with a bunch of items with checkboxes. If the checkboxes are checked, a value is calculated. However, after the application is terminated, the listview resets itself, with all checkboxes being unticked again. How would I have it so when the application is completely terminated, the checkboxes checked/unchecked states are saved? I've looked up various methods but all seem rather complicated for a beginner :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to try [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Also, there is a APIDemo of using `SharedPreferences` here: [APIDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/PersistentState.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to do just that, along with a simple example to follow:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you should save your checkbox settings to `SharedPreferences`.  The basic idea is that within your `onPause()` method you read the state of your UI and write these values into the preferences.  Then in `onResume()` your read these values back and re-populate the UI.

The example in the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) link puts the saving of preferences in `onStop()`, however the android [Application fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) state that:

> Note the **Killable** column in the table above. It indicates whether or not the system can kill the process hosting the activity *at any time after the method returns, without executing another line of the activity's code*. Three methods (`onPause()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()`) are marked "Yes." Because `onPause()` is the first of the three, it's the only one that's guaranteed to be called before the process is killed — `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` may not be. Therefore, you should use `onPause()` to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage.

As such I would suggest writing to preferences in `onPause()` rather than `onStop()`.